# Pulling the category ID of the post on the page I am on Wordpress and listing the articles belonging to that category

Tags: wordpress

In a post (single.php) I want to list other  posts in the category that post is included in.

```php
<?php
    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>

<ul>
    <?php query_posts( 'showposts=5&orderby=date&cat=$cat_id' ); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Articles in all categories come with this code. However, I only want the articles in the category to which that post belongs to be listed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```php
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) :
        $cat= $category->cat_ID
    ?>
    <?php $args = 'cat=' . $cat . '&orderby=date&order=ASC'; ?>
    <?php query_posts( $args );?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php 
    the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Everything about query_post () is here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/